# checkbox valuechange is fired on setValue

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms, and not able to manage the checkbox valueChanges event.

```
   this.formGroup.get('myCheckbox')?.valueChanges
   .pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
   .subscribe(value => {
     doStuff();
  });
```

it is fired when I do this:

```
 this.formGroup?.get('myCheckbox')?.setValue(value, {emitEvent: false});
```

sometimes "value" is same than previous selected, sometimes it is not. How can I prevent the valueChanges to be fired?